# Thursday it has opened an investigation

Tags: prepositions

EU anti-graft agency OLAF said Thursday it has opened an investigation into alleged misuse of EU funds in Slovakia uncovered by journalist Ján Kuciak, who was killed earlier this year.

Source: https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-anti-fraud-agency-probes-alleged-misuse-of-funds-in-slovakia-olaf-jan-kuciak/

Is it all right that before "Thursday" the preposition "on" is missing?

Comment: Yes, although it's somewhat *headlinese* typical of newspaper stories.  In normal conversation the "on" is expected.

Comment: Sometimes in journalistic sources you will find a string of words devoid of any articles or prepositions. **Bald father unjust pay strike**.

Comment: Although the "best" English will use "on" (I saw him _on_ Thursday), it is common and not considered unacceptable to omit it (I saw him Thursday).

Comment: Of course, sometimes the lack of articles or prepositions makes things very confusing, like **Squad helps dog bite victim**  (Did the squad help a dog bite a victim?) or **Violinist linked to JAL crash blossoms** (Was the violinist linked to something called a "JAL crash blossom"?)

Comment: No preposition is required there.

Comment: I would say that you can say things on days. However, I said Thursday that I would not be explaining why. [example]

Comment: To me (British English speaker) omitting _on_ sounds American. However, if "Thursday" has a preceding qualifier ("this", "next", "last", "every") _on_ is not normally used in British or (I think) American English.

Comment: Just a note, that it is "said Thursday" [that] "it has opened ...", not as your title has it, **Thursday it has opened** which is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a preposition there at all, and it's not because it's headlinese. These are both idiomatic:

> You said Monday that you'd have this finished by Friday.
>
> Monday you said you'd have this finished by Friday.

You could also say "on Monday" there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the 'on' if your intended readership is US (American). If you are aiming for a British readership, it is required.